# Why is the Maintainability Index so low in this C# ctor?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, maintainability

I have a simple C# ctor, which initializes some variables:

```
public RSSSourceData()
{
    RSSVersion = "";
    ChannelTitle = "";
    ChannelLink = "";
    ChannelDescription = "";
    Category = "";
    Copyright = "";
    Language = "";
    PubDate = "";
    ManagingEditor = "";
    FileToProcess = "";
    OnlineSource = "";
}
```

All the variables are `string` variables.

When I ran the Code Metric for the entire project, for this ctor I get a Maintainability Index of 57. I expected it to be much higher, because there is nothing so complex that requires too much maintenance work in attributing values to variables.

What am I doing wrong here?

Later edit: the declaration of the class fields is:

```
   class RSSSourceData
    {
        public string RSSVersion;
        public string ChannelTitle;
        public string ChannelLink;
        public string ChannelDescription; 
        public string Category; 
        public string Copyright;
        public string Language; 
        public string PubDate; 
        public string ManagingEditor; 
        public List<string> NewsTitle = new List<string>(); 
        public List<string> NewsLink = new List<string>(); 
        public List<string> NewsDescription = new List<string>();     
        private string OnlineSource; 
        private string FileToProcess; 
        private List<string> FileContent = new List<string>();
```

(...methods come here)

Comment: Or just initialize your fields and properties where you declare them.

Comment: The most significant factor is the lines of code, try deleting one or two lines and see if it gets higher

Comment: @kennyzx I wrote everything on a single line of code and the score went up to 67. Haha, weird.

Comment: Dont let that bother you. We all have classes that we write once and after that its like a black box. Just dont have too much black boxes :)

Comment: Why assign `RSSVersion` in the constructor? Why not use `public string RSSVersion = "";` instead?

Comment: @mjwills Very good point. After revisiting the class logic, I made a few tweaks to the code, making those assignments useless. So, I removed them.

Comment: I don't really find this 'Maintainability Index' useful, it is much like the [Comfort Index](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_comfort_index) in the weather channel. A high Maintainability Index doesn't mean that the code is well written.

Comment: @mjwills now it's up to 73, having an empty ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields has been initialized with contsants. In your example they are empty. In common case they will have some values.

So if you need to change initial values you will need to dive into source code.

That is why maintainability is high.

Comment: Yes, this was the case now.

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer is that it's affected by lines of code.

A long answer is that it's really hard to maintain.

1. Why this class/ctor should maintain so many states at one time?
2. Does any property/field depend on previous property/field initialization?
3. When it gets longer, how could you make sure no missing protperty/field, or duplicated initialization?
4. Do this class still follow high cohesion?
5. If it's data contract class, can it be auto generated?

Comment: By "states" you mean "properties"?